# How can I call a list of images from a child in Firebase Realtime Database to a recycler view in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is how my database is set up in Firebase Realtime Database]
Please I have no idea how to call a list like this into a recycler view in Android Studio, Any ideas on how I can do this will be appreciated.

Comment: The picture you're showing is a document in Firestore, but your code is using Firebase Storage, which is a completely different product.  And you've tagged this with Firebase Realtime Database, which is yet another different product.  Give all this confusion, it's hard to tell what's wrong.  Please edit the question to be more clear about what you've done and how it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: The ` .listAll()` API call from the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage will just list the files in the storage folder, but as Doug says your screenshot is from one of the databases (either Realtime Database or Firestore). The API for each of these products is completely separate, so if you want to read that data from the database, you'll need to use that database's API to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display those URLs in a RecylerView on Android using Java, please use the following steps:

Add these dependencies inside `build.grade` file Module file:

```
implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
```

Create a `.XML` file that contains a `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
```

Create a layout for each image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@null"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Create an adapter class:

```
public class UrlsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UrlsAdapter.UrlViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> urls;

    public UrlsAdapter(Context context, List<String> urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UrlViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
        return new UrlViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UrlViewHolder urlViewHolder, int position) {
        String url = urls.get(position);
        urlViewHolder.bind(url);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    class UrlViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View itemView;
        ImageView imageView;

        UrlViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }

        void bind(String url) {
            Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a global variable of type List inside your activity:

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
```

Find the `RecyclerView` in your activity and create the adapter:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
UrlsAdapter urlsAdapter = new UrlsAdapter(this, urls);
recyclerView.setAdapter(urlsAdapter);
```

Get the `urls` from the Realtime Database and notify the adapter:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference imageUrlsRef = db.child("Listings").child(uid).child("imageUrls");
imageUrlsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String url = ds.getValue(String.class);
                urls.add(url);
            }
            urlsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Now you should see a `RecyclerView` that displays a list of images with the help of the `Glide` library.

Comment: Hey John. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: At first it did not work, until I added "setHasFixedSized"                  
  "property_recycler = findViewById(R.id.property_recycler);
        property_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        property_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        UrlsAdapter urlsAdapter = new UrlsAdapter(this, urls);" thank you very much